# Is there a fast way to make lamp brighter?

Tags: light

I found it too long to go into the lamp's object data every time I want to make it brighter.
Light sources have the empty property "scale". If usual "scaling" hotkey ("S") could make the lamp a bit lighter, tons of my time would be saved.

Comment: I think Blender should work this way: select an object and right click should open a pop-up with all the features of the selected object that are usually listed in the Properties panel, like materials, modifiers, data, etc... it would make the things much faster  :/

Comment: Hello :). You can pin the light properties panel, so it stays always visible, using the pin icon.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @JachymMichal, Just keep the lamp section open on the properties window.

There is a good reason to keep intensity of the light as a completely separate control.

Intensity and lamp size are two very different qualities.

Scaling the light it will just change the quality of the shadow. A very smalll light source will give a very defined sharp shadow. A large source will yield softer less defined shadows.

Answer (score 1):

There are no built in tools to do this, however you can make one with Python quite easily. There is this template for a modal operator that already has all the needed functionality to do this with mouse. I opened it from the text editor's header menu Templates -> Python -> Operator Modal. I had a look at some other templates and copied and changed some code as well.

You could save this code with Blender's text editor and .py file extension and install the file as an add-on and you will have interactive light power adjustment with horizontal mouse movement associated with letter L as a hotkey while in 3d View:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Adjust Light Power",
    "author": "Martynas Žiemys",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 83, 0),
    "location": "L in the viewport",
    "description": "Quickly adjusts power of lights with mouse ",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "Object",
}

import bpy
from bpy.props import IntProperty, FloatProperty


class AdjustLightPower(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Adjust Light Power"""
    bl_idname = "object.adjust_light_power"
    bl_label = "Adjust Light Power"

    first_mouse_x: IntProperty()
    first_value: FloatProperty()
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.object.type == 'LIGHT'

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type == 'MOUSEMOVE':
            delta = self.first_mouse_x - event.mouse_x
            context.object.data.energy = self.first_value + delta * -0.05
            context.area.header_text_set("Light Power: " + str(context.object.data.energy))

        elif event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE':
            context.area.header_text_set(None)
            return {'FINISHED'}

        elif event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            context.object.data.energy = self.first_value
            context.area.header_text_set(None)
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        if context.object:
            self.first_mouse_x = event.mouse_x
            self.first_value = context.object.data.energy

            context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

addon_keymaps = []
def registerKeymaps():
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    if wm.keyconfigs.addon:
        km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='3D View', space_type='VIEW_3D')
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new('object.adjust_light_power', 'L', 'PRESS', shift=False, alt=False,ctrl=False)
        addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))


def unregisterKeymaps():
    for km, kmi in addon_keymaps:
        km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
    addon_keymaps.clear()

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(AdjustLightPower)
    registerKeymaps()


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(AdjustLightPower)
    unregisterKeymaps()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Unfortunately this does not work with numerical input in operation, but it might be possible to add that functionality as well if needed.